# Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox multiple values

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have below codes

```
foreach ($this->getChitsInstallment() as $key => $installment) {
            $checkElement = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox("installment[]");
            $checkElement->setAttrib('id', 'installment_'.$key)->setDecorators($decorators->elementDecorators);
            $this->addElement($checkElement); 
            $checkElements[] = $checkElement->getName();

            $textElement = new Zend_Form_Element_Text("installmentvalue[$key]");
            $textElement->setAttrib('readonly', 'true')->setAttrib('class', 'inp-form');
            $textElement->setAttrib('id', 'text_'.$key)->setDecorators($decorators->elementDecorators); 
            $textElement->setValue($installment);
            $textElement->setLabel("Installment $key: ");
            $this->addElement($textElement);
            $textElements[] = $textElement->getName();

        }
```

I want an output like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="installment[]" id="installment_1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="installment[]" id="installment_2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="installment[]" id="installment_3" />
```

In view i just call `<?php echo $this->form ?>` Only

Pls give me a solution for this

Regards
Nisanth

Comment: You have not explained what's wrong or what error you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox` instead:

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('installment');
foreach ($this->getChitsInstallment() as $key => $installment) {
    $element->addMultiOption($installment, "Installment $key: ");
}
$this->addElement($element);
```